# Remove newlines from a regex matched string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a string as below:

```
Financial strain:       No\n?Food insecurity:\nWorry:                            No\nInability:                        No\n?Transportation needs:\nMedical:                          No\nNon-medical:                      No\nTobacco Use\n?Smoking status:                  Never Smoker\n?
```

I want to first match the substring/sentence of interest (I.e. the sentence beginning with "Food insecurity" and ending with "\n?") then remove all the newlines in this sentence apart from the last one i.e. the one before the question mark.

I have been able to match the sentence w/o its last newline and question mark with regex `(Food insecurity:).*?(?=\\n\?)` but I struggle to remove the first 2 newlines of the matched sentence and return the whole preprocessed string. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
inp = "Financial strain:       No\n?Food insecurity:\nWorry:                            No\nInability:                        No\n?Transportation needs:\nMedical:                          No\nNon-medical:                      No\nTobacco Use\n?Smoking status:                  Never Smoker\n?"
output = re.sub(r'Food insecurity:\nWorry:                            No\nInability:                        No(?=\n\?)', lambda m: m.group().replace('\n', ''), inp)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I wanted to match the substring/sentence of interest (I.e. the sentence beginning with "Food insecurity" and ending with "\n?"). I have tried `re.sub(re.compile("(Food insecurity:).*?(?=\\n\?)"), lambda m: m.group().replace('\n', ''), inp)` but doesn't seem to remove the first two newlines

Comment: @Blue482 My answer is doing exactly what your question (and comment) have stated.  Maybe you asked the wrong question?

Comment: Thanks again @TIm! I will edit my question now. Appreciated.

Comment: Please [check this demo](https://rextester.com/QOGWI30431) and look at the before and after to see if your ask is really want you want.

Comment: Thanks @TIm! Can I please ask how to fix `re.sub(r"(Food insecurity:).*?(?=\\n\?)", lambda m: m.group().replace('\n', ''), inp)` to work?

Comment: Why not use my version?  I use a callback which does a blanket replace of `\n` on the entire match.  This way, you don't have to worry about capture groups.

Comment: Because if the sentence has one more or one less white space for example, it will not be matched and thus the exact two newlines it still has will not be removed.

Comment: Check out [this version](https://rextester.com/LJHVN78030).

Comment: Many thanks! I have modified your version to `re.sub(r"(Food insecurity:\n.*\n.*)(?=\n\?)", lambda m: m.group(1).replace('\n', ' '), inp)` and now it works better! It seems the original match i.e. `(Food insecurity:).*?(?=\\n\?)` doesn't work because it doesn't have the newlines in it (?)... still not quite sure why tho